# How to allow getopt and get_long_opt to handle arbitrary arguments too without emitting error?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am writing a program A which on it's turn invokes arbitrary program B.
When invoking A, some arguments are required by A while some others should be redirected to B, but they are unknown for A.

How can I get A collect those arguments passed to it, however unrecognized
, into a dictionary maybe. So far, every time I use:

```
getopt_long_only(argc, argv, "...
```

or

```
getopt(argc, argv, "...
```

I am getting errors emitted for "unrecognized option" or "illegal option". And those are indeed unrecognized for A, but I want A to ignore that, do you think this is doable?

Comment: You're going to need an argument to `A` that indicates that the rest of arguments should be forwarded to `B`. According to the man page for `getopt`, a double dash `--` on the command line will cause `getopt` to signal the end of argument processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the problem is extremely tricky, even intractable unless you set some ground rules for how your program is to be used.

You can suppress the automatic messages by setting `opterr = 0;` before you call your option parser.  That, unfortunately, is the easy part.

Suppose you're given a command line:

```
wrapper_program -baxt cantaloupe -d designator
```

Further, suppose that neither `-b` nor `-d` is an option to the wrapper program.  The difficulty is now determining whether the `-b` option takes an argument (in which case the argument is `axt`) or it does not. If `-b` doesn't take an argument, there are extra options starting with `-a` — but does that take an argument (which would be `xt`) or is the `x` also an option? And if `x` is an option, does that take an argument (which would be the `t`) or is the `t` an option too — and does that take an argument (which would be `cantaloupe`).  If the first argument `-baxt` has an option with an argument attached, then do you want the `cantaloupe` option to end the argument parsing, or should the code do GNU-style argument permutation?  If it should do argument permutation, does the `-d` option take an argument (`designator`) or is that a non-option argument?

You can set ground rules to sort this sort of thing out, but you have to think hard and code carefully — and test thoroughly.  It is probably easier if you know whether the wrapped program takes long or short arguments.

You might find it better to demand that options for the wrapped program follow a double-dash:

```
wrapper_program -w wrapper-argument -- -b=axt -d designator cantaloupe
```

The idea is that the arguments to the wrapper program precede the `--` and the arguments to the wrapped program follow it.  This gives a clean, clear separation between the two sets of arguments.

An alternative is to have a 'pass-through' option (the C compilers often support this with notations such as `-Wl,-arg-for-linker`).  For example, the `-p` option might take an argument which will be passed verbatim to the wrapped program:

```
wrapper_program -w wrapper-argument -p -b=axt -p -d -p designator cantaloupe
```

The `-p` options specify that the following argument should be passed to the wrapped program.

Using the `-b=axt` notation implies the use of `getopt_long()` rather than `getopt()`, though if `-b` takes an argument then the `=axt` option will be treated as the argument by `getopt()` whereas `getopt_long()` would, AFAIK, treat `axt` as the argument.

Be cautious about such designs.  They're neither easy to write nor necessarily easy to use.